# marquee issue with chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, marquee

i'm using marquee it words fine n FF but the content disappears as soon as the beginning of content reached the end of the marquee http://www.mawk3y.net/alsoos/kaseem/
HTML code

```
<div class="news">
<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="20" direction="right" onmouseover="stop()" onmouseout="start()">
<a href="#">تجرية الشريط الاخباري</a><a href="#">تجرية الشريط الاخباري</a><a href="#">تجرية الشريط الاخباري</a>
</marquee>
```

css code:

```
.news, marquee{
width:904px;
height:42px;
float:right;
}
.news a{
line-height:42px;
height:42px;
float:right;
display:inline-block;
float:right;
padding:0 10px; 
}
```

Comment: *sidenote:* `<marquee>` tag is obsoleted. Do not use it & replace it with CSS / JS animation. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hello please user smoothdivscroll js css
```

[smoothdivscroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The marquee tag is deprecated. You should probably use CSS and/or javascrpit to achive the best result.

Comment: Well, this is not an answer, rather a comment, and my comment said exactly the same thing

Answer (score 1):

perhaps create your own in jquery, should be pretty easy to do. Here has some good examples

http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html

more control too!